How do I find the contract address for a coin on solscan?
for example: https://solscan.io/token/5oVNBeEEQvYi1cX3ir8Dx5n1P7pdxydbGF2X4TxVusJm
is it the token address?

Yes
The Token address is commonly referred to as

Contract address
Mint address


I am going to assume that you are coming from an EVM background.
Tokens on Solana are managed by the token program hence no need to deploy a contract to launch your token.
Tokens on Solana documentation -> https://solana.com/docs/core/tokens
